# Create a new project in a new window in clion

Tags: c++, clion

I'm new to Clion and every time I created a new c++ project, the system always pop up saying whether I want to create in this window or a new window. I accidentally chose "in this window" and clicked "don't ask me again"; however, I wanted to choose "new window". Is there a way to change this. Can't find in the preferences in clion. I'm using Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Opening an existing project is affected by the *Project Opening* option in *Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings*. It's probably the same option for new projects.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I forgot to say i'm using mac. I only see file colors and scopes under Appearance & Behaviour.

Comment: Not the `File -> Default Settings` menu item, but `File -> Settings`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. But I only see default settings, import settings and export settings.

Comment: There must be a `Settings...` item in *some* menu. Keep looking.

Comment: This is not programming question at all. Consider asking this question on `superuser`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, still can't find it but I fixed it by resetting default.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph No but it's about an IDE (i.e. a "software tool[s] commonly used by programmers") which is on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings**

There's a section for **Project Opening** which has the **Open project in new window** option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **CLion > Preferences** on Mac.  Had the same issue, their's only "Default Settings..." under **File**